# How to make sure replies stay in the same thread IN BOTH ACCOUNTS when using the gmail API?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I managed to use the email headers (References and In-Reply-To) to get it to show up in the same thread when I reply, but when we exchange emails again after that they appear in a new thread

I expected them to be in the same thread